# problem with anaconda environment location

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment

I'm trying to create a python environment using anaconda at a specific location (file path).

According to the conda documentation page, I should use the --prefix parameter to inform the full path to environment.
When using that prefix, the environment is created without a name (parameters prefix and name cannot be used together) - see the image bellow - which makes environment activation a bit strange (having to use the full path).

Furthermore, I couldn't find a way of removing a environment that does not have a name (see error bellow).

Does anyone know if that lack of name is an expected behavior? And id it is, how to remove the env? 
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the lack of name is an expected behaviour when you create an environment specifying a prefix.

The easiest way to remove an environment created with prefix is to specify the prefix path again at removal:

```
conda env remove --prefix=c:/fooEnv2
```

Comment: ah so simple. thanks very much. Do you know by nay chance why the lack of name?

Comment: Sorry this is late because I'm scanning stack overflow for a similar env issue: it looks like you have no name because you didn't specify one. In your `conda create` line you are missing the `-n myenv` argument where `myenv` is the environment name https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands